# SQLAlchemy Insert executemany Func

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to bulk insert a list of dicts into a MySQL database via SQLAlchemy.  Inside the list each dict has time and temperature.  The time values are as an ISO time string.  I am trying to have MySQL use the STR_TO_DATE function on the way in to create datetime objects to store to the database.

I have sucessfully had this working via insert().values({'time':func.STR_TO_DATE(row.time, date_str), 'temp' = row.temp})

Example Code:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, func
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import DATETIME, INTEGER, insert

temp_data = [{'time':'2019-02-07T14:01:00.000000000Z', 'temperature':68},
             {'time':'2019-02-07T14:02:00.000000000Z', 'temperature':69},
             {'time':'2019-02-07T14:03:00.000000000Z', 'temperature':70},
             {'time':'2019-02-07T14:04:00.000000000Z', 'temperature':71}]


date_string = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S.%f000Z'
mysql_metadata = MetaData()
mysql_table = Table('temperature', mysql_metadata,
                    Column('time', DATETIME(fsp = 6), primary_key = True),
                    Column('temperature', INTEGER()))

def single_insert():
    engine = create_engine('mysql://test_user:test@localhost/temperature',
                                  echo = False)
    mysql_table.drop(engine, checkfirst = True)
    mysql_table.create(engine)
    conn = engine.connect()
    for row in temp_data:
        conn.execute(mysql_table.insert().values(time = func.STR_TO_DATE(row['time'], date_string),
                                                 temperature = row['temperature']))



def insert_many():
    engine = create_engine('mysql://test_user:test@localhost/temperature',
                                  echo = False)    
    mysql_table.drop(engine, checkfirst = True)
    mysql_table.create(engine)
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute(mysql_table.insert(), temp_data)
```

Not sure how to go about getting this to work by binding a parameter to a single input value that can call the STR_TO_DATE so data can be inserted via a list of dicts.

Second Edit:

Here is my brute force code that works.  Trying to find a way to use SQLALchemy Core to complete this statement.

```
def insert_many():
    engine = create_engine('mysql://test_user:test@localhost/temperature',
                                  echo = True)    
    mysql_table.drop(engine, checkfirst = True)
    mysql_table.create(engine)
    conn = engine.connect()
    stmt = text("INSERT INTO temperature VALUES( STR_TO_DATE(:time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S.%f000Z'), :temperature)")
    conn.execute(stmt, temp_data)
```

Third Edit:

Eventually want to do a profile against Python Datetime strptime vs the MySQL method.   Looking to see which is faster.

Comment: No idea what the issue is without actual code. Please give a [mcve]

Answer (score 5):

One way to do the bulk insertion for list of dictionaries is by using [bindparam](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam) for each key and perform execute

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam

temp_data = [{'time':'2019-02-07T14:01:00.000000000Z', 'temperature':68},
         {'time':'2019-02-07T14:02:00.000000000Z', 'temperature':69},
         {'time':'2019-02-07T14:03:00.000000000Z', 'temperature':70},
         {'time':'2019-02-07T14:04:00.000000000Z', 'temperature':71}]

def insert_many():

    engine = create_engine('mysql://test_user:test@localhost/temperature',
                              echo = False)    
    mysql_table.drop(engine, checkfirst = True)
    mysql_table.create(engine)
    conn = engine.connect()

    statement = Mysql_table.insert().values({
            'time' : bindparam('time'),
            'temperature' : bindparam('temperature')
            })
    conn.execute(statement, temp_data)
    conn.close()
```

Regarding the STR_TO_DATE function , how about updating those values in the dictionary itself and then executing the insert_many() function

```
for item in temp_data:
    item.update((k, func.STR_TO_DATE(v)) for k,v in item.items() if k == 'time')
```

You can always use the time module to measure time execution

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
start_time = time.time()
func.STR_TO_DATE('date_value') # datetime.strptime(date_string, "%d %B, %Y")
print('--%s seconds --' %(time.time() - start_time)
```

Answer (score 4):

SQLAlchemy (SA) [doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/performance/bulk_inserts.html) has this example at the bottom of the page that illustrates the use of DBAPI's API *executemany* over the SA Core engine. I think the code sample is invalid (you just need the raw values in the *args*, no field names, if your engine's dialect uses positional inserts), but it shows the necessary calls. Keep in mind that *executemany* takes the SQL statement string, so the *bindparams* portion is only used to assist building the string - you may find it simpler to just write the statement as text and ax the *bindparams* part. However, you may try *bindparams* first to see how SA generates the statement for your data types in scope.

The advantage of this method is that true *executemany* is optimized in the DBAPI if you use a popular backend (as MySQL).

In the more modern syntax than the one used in the example, the SA connection should be opened by calling *engine.raw_connection()*